# Изменение состояния кнопки при длительном нажатии на нее

Tags: android, button, listener

Здравствуйте,

в приложении использую макет 2 кнопки "٨""٧" и поле в котором при нажатии одной из кнопок значение увеличивается, а другой уменьшается. Причем при длительном нажатии коэффициент инкрементация (декрементация) начинает расти, т.о. значение в поле начинает изменяться с ускорением.

Заметил такую вещь что если на кнопку долго нажимать, и не отпускать пальца с экрана она мигает, т.е.  изменяет свое состояние. Получается бесконечно долго нельзя нажимать на кнопку, она все равно в какой-то момент мигнет, изменить состояние.

Подскажите пожалуйста почему кнопка меняет свое состояние при длительном нажатии ? (т.е. я пальцем прикоснулся экрана, где кнопка, и палец не отвожу от экрана, а кнопка тем ни менее меняет свое состояние)

Можно ли как-то преодолеть такую проблему ?

Заранее спасибо большое всем за помощь.

Comment: Возможно это пригодится Вам http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938516/continuously-increase-integer-value-as-the-button-is-pressed

Comment: @АндрейКасьянов, спасибо, эту тему я как раз и брал за основу когда делал свой модуль. Но тут проблема другая. модуль работает как надо. Проблема в том что сам xml объект кнопки если на него долго нажимать, фиксирует ложные события. Т.е. я держу палец на кнопке, а она почему-то время от времени генерирует событие нажатие кнопки, (на экране в это время кнопка мигает).

Answer (score 1):

Используй OnTouchListener вместо OnClick;
http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/167-urok-102-touch-obrabotka-kasanija.html

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ. но это я и так использую `OnTouchListener` . В своей программе. Не знаю возможно у меня сенсор у планшета, какой-то особенный. Но я проводил эксперимент: выводил кнопку просто как xml объект ( без привязки какой-либо логики и слушателей). Затем нажимаю на кнопку и держу эту кнопку нажатой и хотя я и не убираю пальца с кнопки, она все равно мигает время от времени. Т.е. по логике срабатывают `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` и `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`.

Comment: А эти команды не должны срабатывать ,потому как палец я с кнопки не убираю. Вопрос в том как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку она не дергалась т.е. не срабатывали ложные `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` и `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` ?

Comment: Замени кнопки - на Image кто знает может это быстро решит твою проблему ...